# How provide dynamic message in custom loopback validation?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

[Here](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-validate) is from documentation:

```
User.validate('name', customValidator, {message: 'Bad name'});
function customValidator(err) {
    if (this.name === 'bad') err();
});
var user = new User({name: 'Peter'});
user.isValid(); // true
user.name = 'bad';
user.isValid(); // false
```

Is there a way to modify `message` variable during validation? For example, `this.name === 'bad'` the message is `Bad name` but when `this.name === 'very bad'` the message should be `Very Bad name`. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddenly there is a `addError` method with signature `errors.add(attr, message, code)`, so:

```
User.validate('name', customValidator);
function customValidator(err) {
    if (this.name === 'bad') {
        this.errors.add('name', `Name is bad`, 'name.bad')
        err();
    }
    if (this.name === 'very bad') {
        this.errors.add('name', `Name is very bad`, 'name.very.bad')
        err();
    }
});
```

This works, but keep in mind that you will have **+1** `custom` code and message, see `error.details.codes.name` and `error.details.messages.name` paths from rough json below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 422,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "The `Entity` instance is not valid. Details: `name` Name is very bad (value: very bad).",
    "details": {
      "context": "Entity",
      "codes": {
        "name": [
          "name.very.bad",
          "custom"
        ],
        },
      "messages": {
        "name": [
          "Name is very bad",
          "is invalid"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stack": "..."
  }
}
```