# How perform entire model validation in loopback?

Tags: javascript, validation, loopbackjs

Consider the following example:
Suppose there is a object with `enum` property. If `enum` property has `5` value, the field `value` should be equal to 5, if `enum` is `super` object must have properties `up` and `down`. So the js code can be like that:

```
if (obj.enum === 5) {
    if (obj.value != 5) {
        //error here
    } 
}

if (obj.enum === 'super') {
    if (obj.up === undefined || obj.down === undefined ) {
        //error here
    }
}
```

How to integrate this code into loopbackjs???

E.g. this **is** not a fields validation (custom or not), this it **model validation**. So `isValid` funciton (see below) and `validate` method can not be used. The `validate` validates **only one property**.

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631763/can-i-define-a-custom-validation-with-options-for-loopback) is very similar question but it ended up with custiom **property** validation.
2. [Here](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-prototype-isvalid) is example with `isValid` funciton in `validatable.js`. Please note that this only invoking validation, there is no way to add additional errors or add additional validation

Comment: Have you looked up here? http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Validating-model-data.html And how and where do you want to get the error code back?

Comment: I looked here several times :) `And how and where do you want to get the error code back?` via loopback mechanisms, I do not know how do they manage dynamic error codes. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967001/1251549) answer as workaround. Pass one of always present fields to `validate` method and add custom error code and messages inside `customValidator` funciton.